# PHP strtotime is wrong (some times)?

Tags: php

I have this issue with strtotime in my PHP code that it is wrong sometimes (only for some timezones) and it is correct for others!!

I cannot get my head around it.

I have set the `<?php date_default_timezone_set('GMT'); ?>` at the top of my page as well but that doesn't help!

basically what it does is that it will add or subtract the `offset/3600` value to the set time in `$time1 = strtotime('00:00');` depending on the if and else if conditions.

the offset/3660 value is the time difference between two timezones!

the code bellow works for some locations and it doesn't for others! basically it will add an extra 1-2 hours or takes off/subtract an extra 1-2 hours some times (not all the time).

i.e. the time difference between Abidjan and london is -1. 
the time (value) that should be shown is 23:00 as 00:00 - 01:00 = 23:00. but the value is shown is 00:00.

However as i mentioned it works for some timezones.
i.e. for the time difference between New York and London which is -5 the code works and it shows 19:00 as 00:00 - 05:00 = 19:00

could someone please shed a light on this?

here is the code in question:

```
<?php
$time1 = strtotime('00:00');

if (0 > $offset)
{
   // For negative offset (hours behind)
  $hour_dif = date('H:i', strtotime($time1 -$offset/3600));
  $time1 = "{$hour_dif}";
}
elseif (0 < $offset)
{
   // For positive offset (hours ahead)
     $hour_dif = date('H:i', strtotime($time1 +$offset/3600));
     $time1 = "{$hour_dif}";

}
else
{
   // For offsets in the same timezone.
   $time1 = "in the same timezone";
}

echo "{$time1}";
?>
```

Comment: Where are you setting $offset?

Comment: Are you taking into account differences in DST between timezones?  (i.e. some timezones don't have DST; some regions within a timezone don't honor DST, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time_by_country for an idea of how complicated it is)

Comment: Are you aware of PHP's `DateTime` class which alleviates the need for you to come up with "smart" solutions for calculating differences and intervals manually?

Comment: @N.B. Yes, and i had a look at it and it was not what I expected at all. also, it seems quite unnecessarily complicated.

Comment: So having 3 lines of code is more complex than this mess you created?

Comment: @N.B. which part of this is 3 lines of code please? http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Answer (score 3):

Well, since `strtotime()` already returns a timestamp and `date()` expects one you could just do

```
$hour_dif = date('H:i', ($time1 - ($offset*3600)));
```

or

```
$hour_dif = date('H:i', ($time1 + ($offset*3600)));
```

respectively, to remove or add the correct amount of seconds from/to the timestamp.

I am also assuming that `$offset` is the offset in hours, so you would have to multiply by `3600` to get the amount of seconds, not divide.

---

Alright, after testing your code and thinking through it some more, it became obvious.

With a negative offset like `-1` you're going to calculate `$time1 - (-1) * 3600` and we all know that a double negation is positive...

So in fact, your code can be condensed to:

```
$time1 = strtotime('00:00');

if ($offset == 0)
     $time1 = "in the same timezone";
else
{
   // For positive offset (hours ahead)
     $hour_dif = date('H:i', ($time1 + ($offset*3600)));
     $time1 = "{$hour_dif}";
}

echo "{$time1}\n";
```

and should work as expected:

```
cobra@box ~ $ for i in {-24..24}; do php test.php $i; done;
00:00
01:00
02:00
03:00
04:00
05:00
06:00
07:00
08:00
09:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00
18:00
19:00
20:00
21:00
22:00
23:00
in the same timezone
01:00
02:00
03:00
04:00
05:00
06:00
07:00
08:00
09:00
10:00
11:00
12:00
13:00
14:00
15:00
16:00
17:00
18:00
19:00
20:00
21:00
22:00
23:00
00:00
```

Comment: I did try your suggestion and it is still the same.

Comment: in fact now with your suggestion, it will show the result for New York and London like this: 14:42 which is wrong.

Comment: it is not working I'm afraid. now it will return all the values as 00:00

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx Alright I've dug through it, the final edited part of my answer should give the proper result.

Comment: still returns all the values like so: 00:00

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx I've added the output of a very simple unit test I constructed by adding `$offset = $argv[1]`. `00:00` is only printed when it's expected.

Comment: anyway I can get in the chat with you please mate? my reputation is not enough (i don't think).

Comment: Unfortunately it won't allow me to chat as it says: You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here.

Comment: its the so close but so far scenario :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36399/discussion-between-energylynx-energylynx-and-cobra-fast)