# function's value in PHP DateTime?

Tags: php

okay, I am at my wits end with this. been trying to solve this for 3 days now and I am getting nowhere with this.

I need to get the value of `$offset` between two locations and take it off of a set time which is `(00:00)`.

here is how I set the `$offset` value and it works just fine.

```
<?php

if( isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    //be sure to validate and clean your variables
    $timezone1 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone1']);
    $timezone2 = htmlentities($_POST['timezone2']);

    //then you can use them in a PHP function. 
    function get_timezone_offset( $origin_tz, $remote_tz ) {
        $timezone1 = new DateTimeZone ( $origin_tz );
        $timezone2 = new DateTimeZone ( $remote_tz );

        $datetime1 = new DateTime ("now", $timezone1);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime ("now", $timezone2);

        $offset = $timezone1->getOffset($datetime1) - $timezone2->getOffset($datetime2);
        return $offset;

    }

$offset = get_timezone_offset($timezone1, $timezone2);

}

?>
```

**And here is how I've tried to do what i want using DateTime, this code will only echo's the `$offset` value without taking it off of the 00:00**

```
<?php
if (0 > $offset)
{
// set an object with the current date
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTime(00, 00);

// the second date
$date2 = new DateTime($offset/3600 * 1);

// apply the diff() method, getting a DateInterval object ($diDiff)
$diDiff = $date->diff($date2) ;
}
echo $diDiff->format("%H:%i");
?>
```

**And i even tried to use `strtotime` but strtotime returns a wrong value and i have been advised by some guys on stackoverflow to use DateTime.**

```
<?php
$time1 = strtotime('00:00');

if (0 > $offset)
{
   // For negative offset (hours behind)
  $hour_dif = date('H:i', strtotime($time1 -$offset/3600));
  $time1 = "{$hour_dif}";
}
elseif (0 < $offset)
{
   // For positive offset (hours ahead)
     $hour_dif = date('H:i', strtotime($time1 +$offset/3600));
     $time1 = "{$hour_dif}";

}
else
{
   // For offsets in the same timezone.
   $time1 = "in the same timezone";
}

echo "{$time1}";
?>
```

Please someone help me out as it is absolutely killing my time.

Comment: Previous question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18490086

Comment: @Cobra_Fast, Yes mate, I have asked this probably from 4-5 php experts and they were stumbled with it same as yourself. :)

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @Cups, PHP Version 5.3.26.

Comment: @SalmanA, its very simple, the $offset is a value of time difference between two location/timezones. what i need to do is to take off the value of $offset (whatever it is as long as it is smaller than 0. i.e. -1, -2, -3 etc) from a set time of 00:00. thats all...

Comment: @OP thx, thought I'd ask as DateTime did not arrive perfectly formed, it developed between 5.1 and 5.3 IIRC

Answer (score 0):

The following code will print the input time adjusted by `$offset` amount of hours.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTime(00, 00);

$date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("{$offset} hours"));

echo $date->format('H:i');
```

I have, again, tested this solution (with PHP 5.4.17) and it correctly shifts the time.

PHPFiddle: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/rhd-pj4

Comment: I really don't know how you've tested it without any error's mate because i get this error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function format() on a non-object on line 1920` and on line 1920 is this: echo `$date->format('H:i');` and i even changed it to `$date->format('%H:%i');` and still the same!

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx That means, that `$date` does no longer contain a `DateTime` object at the point where `->format()` is called. Maybe you are changing the variable in between?

Comment: No, I am not changing the variables at all.

Comment: Hanag on, i seem to found whats wrong with your code! where do you take off the $offset value from 00:00 ?! you only set $date->setTime(00, 00); and you won't take the $offset value from that! thats why it just shows 00:00 when the $offset value is smaller than 0...

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx I take the offset value off at `$date->add(...);`.

Comment: well its not taking it off as it only echo's 00:00.

Comment: Okay, I literally took this part of your code and edited the timezone1 and placed in my page and now i get this echo-ed out:  `Time at offset 12600: 00:00` or `Time at offset 18000: 00:00` etc...

Comment: `<?php
$timezone1 = (isset($_POST['timezone1']) ? (int)$_POST['timezone1'] : 0);

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTime(00, 00);

$date->add(DateInterval::createFromDateString("{$offset} hours"));

echo "Time at offset {$offset}: " . $date->format('H:i') . "\n";

?>`

Comment: @EnergyLynxEnergyLynx Where are you defining `$offset`? The thing takes the offset in hours in the variable `$offset` not some timezone data.

Comment: if you remember in the chat yesterday, I am defining the `$offset` in the first code on this post and the user can choose 2 timezone locations from 2 dropdown lists (`timezone1`) and (`timezone2`) and the `$offset` is the time difference between those two locations. the `timezone1` and `timezone2` are identical and they just contain the PHP supported timezones. This part works just as it should with my first code on this post and the dropdown lists.

Comment: the timezone1 and timezone2 are like this: `<select style="font-size:9px;" name="timezone2" id="timezone2" class="timezone2">
                        <?php
                    foreach($options as $key => $value)
                    {
                        echo '<option value="'. $key .'" label="'. $value .'">'.$value.'</option>';
                    }
                    ?>
<option value="Africa/Abidjan" label="Abidjan">Abidjan</option>
<option value="Erope/London" label="Accra">Accra</option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

You can also easily solve this using [Carbon](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon), a class that will greatly simplify doing  date calculations of any kind:

```
// example timezones
$timezone1 = 'Europe/Berlin'; 
$timezone2 = 'Asia/Yakutsk'; 

$dt1 = Carbon::createFromDate(2000, 1, 1, $timezone1);
$dt2 = Carbon::createFromDate(2000, 1, 1, $timezone2);

// false will force a relative difference, so it can be a negative result
$difference = $dt1->diffInMinutes($dt2, false);

$dtMidnight = Carbon::create(2000, 1, 1, 12, 0, 0);

// get the difference from midnight
$differenceFromMidnight = $dtMidnight->addMinutes($difference);

echo $differenceFromMidnight->hour;
echo $differenceFromMidnight->minute;
```

Comment: No no, you've missed the point mate. i am not trying to get the difference between timezone as i am already doing that with my first code posted.

Comment: Yes. And the last lines calculate the difference from midnight. That's what you wanted to do, wasn't it.

Comment: I guess as long as it returns the correct value which it dose then i won't be messing about with that part of the code.

Comment: Well, I've tested my code and it works fine. But whatever floats your boat, mate...

Comment: how and what did you tested it with? did you try to test it with my code?

Comment: Why should i test it with your code? My code is a replacement for your code, not an addition for it. And i tested it by running it.

Comment: fair enough. I'm just a bit confused with your code and strategy mate.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/36532/discussion-between-energylynx-energylynx-and-cuewizchris)

Answer (score 0):

This handles both positive and negative offsets:

```
$sign = $offset >= 0 ? 1 : -1;
$offset = $offset * $sign;  // make sure offset is a positive number

// set an object with the current date
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTime(00, 00);

// the second date
$date2 = new DateTime();
$interval = new DateInterval("PT" . $offset . "S");
if ($sign > 0) {
    $date2->add($interval);
} else {
    $date2->sub($interval);
}

echo $date2->format("H:i");
```

Comment: Nope, this will only adds the $offset value to the current time of timezone1 and it it throws out a wrong value for timezone2.